# First and last two numbers of an integer windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, numbers, int

How to get the first two numbers of an integer and the last two in c#.

For example:

```
int complete = 1935;
```

how to make,

```
int firtTwo = 19;
```

and

```
int secondTwo = 35;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it always a four-digit positive value? If so, I'd go for:

```
int hundreds = complete / 100;
int tensAndUnits = complete % 100;
```

If it's *any* arbitrary number, so you'd want "935" to be "93" and "35" you might as well use string operations:

```
string text = complete.ToString();
int first = int.Parse(text.Substring(0, 2));
int last = int.Parse(text.Substring(text.Length - 2, 2));
```

(Note that this will blow up for single-digit values...)

It would help if you could say what this is meant to be *for* though.

Comment: Yes, it is always 4 digit number..how to display firstTwo and lastTwo?

Comment: @Jenish: Well look at `hundreds` and `tensAndUnits`. Those are the two numbers in question. You haven't told us anything about where you want to display them... or basically *anything*.

Comment: Sorry for my short description..but I basically wanted to display it in a textBox and then retrieve the values to two separate LoopingSelectors..but now I got it working using the code you posted, Thanks so much once again